# How to tell google not to index my website on specific keywords?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search

I have 2 websites that have the same brand. One of them should not appear when searching the brand on the search engines.

Do you have an Idea How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If your page url has your brand keyword in it then you can easily disallow the pages from robots.txt
Suppose your brand name and your brand url is **abc brand** and
**xyz.com/best-abc-brand-bags**
 Then your robots.txt should contain this code

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *abc-brand*
```

Google will not crawl that particular brand url

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of informing any search engine not to index a particular website for keywords that appear anywhere on the page or keywords found in the source code. Looking for a cloak and dagger method would also be a one-way ticket to penalty land.

Bottom line, if you don't want a website being shown, don't index it period, or index the pages that the brand is mentioned on.

This sounds like a silly idea to begin with, Search Engines are designed to rank webpages based on Keywords, it goes against everything they are designed to do, and somehow you're assuming there would be a way of telling search bots not to do their job properly.

Comment: There are many multinational companies that have multiple websites and require that only one site can present  the brand .

Comment: That's not what you asked. You asked:  `not to index my website on specific keywords` - which differs from ranking a website with multiple languages which does NOT STOP those sites being indexed for specific keywords; it merely tells Google & search engines which sites are prepared for X region, country or language. Are you asking how to rank similar websites but for different countries or regions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, don't use the keywords you don't want to rank your page on.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to block googlebot based on the your keywords. But you can surely block googlebot to index the page which ranks on the keywords that you want to be blocked. 
Just head to the search console and go to performance reports. Filter with query and enter your keyword. Look for the URL which ranks on that query and block it. If it’s not an important page of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Googleon and Googleoff tags allow you to specify parts of your site to not be indexed. Wrap the content with keywords with googleoff tag.

“Put simply, the googleon/googleoff tags tell GoogleBot Google Search Appliance when to start and stop indexing various parts of the web document.”

https://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/

```
<p>This is normal (X)HTML content that will be indexed by Google.</p>

<!--googleoff: index-->

<p>This (X)HTML content will NOT be      indexed by Google.</p>

<!--googleon: index>
```

Comment: Google bot does not obey Googleon and Googleoff tags. These tags are for Google Search Appliance which is a different product by google and is separate from Google SERPs